# Loading file from eclipse self

Tags: java, file, load

I'm working together with somebody on an assignment and we need to be able to load and save Files. At the moment we do it like this:

```
robot1.getComputer().loadAndCompileProgram(new File("C:\\Projects\\IO\\program1.txt"));
```

However this requires that both he and I have this program in the exact same location. We would prefer to store it in our eclipse Project and being able to load the file regardless of what the "full" location of program1 is in our computer..
We would like to do something like this:

```
robot1.getComputer().loadAndCompileProgram(new File("/Project D3 1.15/Progs/program1.txt"));
```

With Project D3 1.15 being the Java project and the full string the Path in Eclipse of program1. This however doesn't work. Is it possible to do what we want?

Answer (score 0):

Try `new File("./Progs/program1.txt")` or `new File("Progs/program1.txt"")`

Besides that: if you are having problems with finding out how to locate files under different IDEs, just create simple class with main method like this:

```
public class ExpMainClass {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

and run it - this should help understanding from where IDE is executing your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the Eclipse project name, and the real path on the computer.
It is possible to have a project named Foo whose path is C:\Projects\Bar.

However, it is possible to do this, since when you execute from Eclipse, you are in the current directory.

Just do this

```
robot1.getComputer().loadAndCompileProgram(new File("Progs/program1.txt"));
```

or (if you want to specify the project name)

```
robot1.getComputer().loadAndCompileProgram(new File("../Project D3 1.15/Progs/program1.txt"));
```

Comment: that won't work. ".." is taken to refer to the current context. The current context (a.k.a. system path) is the path of the java.exe (or whatever they have on linux) that runs your programs... So ".." points to something like "C:\Java"

Comment: This is wrong, it does work. When launched from Eclipse (which is what was stated by OP) the current context is the Eclipse project's root directory. If the project is named the same that the root directory, then both line of code above will work, otherwise, the first one only.

Comment: Besides, this is easy to test. Create an eclipse project named foobar, create a class whose main method is this `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("../foobar/baz.txt"), "hi!");`. Now execute the program and refresh the project with eclipse. You will see a new file called `baz.txt` inside the `foobar` project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could leverage a Java System Property such as the `user.dir` to get till the workspace and then construct the path.

`new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "program1.txt")`

This would expect the file to be present directly inside your workspace, if running through Eclipse.

This would be a truly platform-independent way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
String myProjectDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
robot1.getComputer().loadAndCompileProgram(new File(myProjectDir +"/myFolder/program1.txt"));
```

The JVM environment variable "user.dir" points to your project directory (for programs that are run from eclipse)